# css pentagon not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I was helping a friend with this - kinda harder than I thought - pentagon with css.

If you open the [this link](http://napstest.net76.net/pentagon.html) you'll get the point, it's just 5 triangles done with css and rotated/aligned to their correct places.

But I wanted to give some animation on mouse hover.  The thing is, as you can test, triangles are drawn but still their div remains rectangular and overlap the other divs. Is there any way to solve this without having to move the triangles farther apart?

Alignments not working as intended in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWmqj/).  Code in jsfiddle seen below

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="pentagontopleft" class="pentagon"></div>
<div id="pentagontopright" class="pentagon"></div><br>
<div id="pentagonbotleft" class="pentagon"></div>
<div id="pentagonbotright" class="pentagon"></div><br>
<div id="pentagonbotmid" class="pentagon"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#pentagontopleft {
  margin:70px 0 5px 150px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotate(144deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(144deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(144deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#pentagontopright {
  margin:70px 0 5px -180px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotate(216deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(216deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(216deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#pentagonbotright {
  margin:-85px 0 5px -80px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotate(288deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(288deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(288deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#pentagonbotleft {
  margin:-85px 0 5px 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotate(72deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(72deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(72deg); /* Safari and Chrome */

}

#pentagonbotmid {
  margin:-150px 0 5px 225px;
  width: 0;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pentagon').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('border-color','red transparent');
  });
  $('.pentagon').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('border-color','#37272e transparent')
  })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried overlaying a map? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: To do it without maps you'd have to use an approach [**like this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837391/how-to-make-a-triangular-shaped-link-without-using-image-map)

Comment: thank you both for the responses, i think the map approach will work for me :)

Comment: I cleaned up your code a bit. Try to use classes instead of IDs most all the time (this way you can have multiple of these things and save writing code for new versions). [Cleaned up version](http://jsfiddle.net/eWmqj/1/). I played around with the method I linked, it is difficult to get correct due to z-index problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for you...

Try overlaying a map! - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Also: http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: [W3 Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Use a Mozilla reference or some other reputable resource when it comes to things like this