# CSS/JS: Is it possible to make a div (with a background image) have a diagonal border rather than a square one

Tags: css, border

Consider the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xNSm2/

In this scenario I've got a div with a `background-image` of a triangle. I also have a div underneath it.

I need both of those divs to be clickable.

I cannot have the red div sit on top of the green div. Red must be underneath.

The only solution I can think of is to have the green div have a diagonal border, rather than a square one. Is this possible?

Comment: `.underlyingDiv {z-index: 2}`. Is it okay for you, or you want to get the "Green div clicked" notice only when you click into green background (not in the whole square link now)?

Comment: That's exactly right @panther - I'd like it to only be noticeable when the background image is clicked, not the empty space.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements] check this link it may be helpful to you

Comment: This may help as well: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837391/how-to-make-a-triangular-shaped-link-without-using-image-map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837391/how-to-make-a-triangular-shaped-link-without-using-image-map)