# Overlapping CSS Anchor Triangles

Tags: css

I am trying to build a navigation menu with overlapping triangles.

I limited the anchor area to the triangle like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837391/how-to-make-a-triangular-shaped-link-without-using-image-map). It works like a charm, ok.

Then when I overlap these triangles, suddenly I can't click it properly..
    [see example](https://jsfiddle.net/srmhha2m/)

HTML:

```
<nav>

            <div class="link select-A">
            <div class="square1"></div>
            <a class="triangle-up" href="#"><span>A</span></a>
            <div class="square2"></div>
            </div> 

            <div class="link select-B">
            <div class="square1"></div>
            <a class="triangle-up" href="#"><span>B</span></a>
            <div class="square2"></div>
            </div> 

            <div class="link select-C">
            <div class="square1"></div>
            <a class="triangle-up" href="#"><span>C</span></a>
            <div class="square2"></div>
            </div> 

            <div class="link select-D">
            <div class="square1"></div>
            <a class="triangle-up" href="#"><span>D</span></a>
            <div class="square2"></div>
            </div> 

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {margin-left:100px}

.link {width:180px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;margin:auto; position:relative; margin-top: 19px; float: left; margin-left: -115px;}
.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:10px;
}
.square1 {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 170px;
   // background: blue;
    top: -44px;
    left: -34px;
    transform: rotate(39deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(39deg);/* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(39deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(39deg); /* Opera */
  -moz-transform: rotate(39deg); /* Firefox */
}
.square2 {
   z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 170px;
 // background: blue;
  top: -63px;
  left: 118px;
  transform: rotate(-39deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-39deg);/* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-39deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(-39deg); /* Opera */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-39deg); /* Firefox */
}
.link span {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
       -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
           transform: rotate(-50deg);
   margin-left: -93px;
   padding-top: 54px;
   display: block;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because  each `.square1` is overlaying the preceding `.link` - See here: https://jsfiddle.net/srmhha2m/2/

Comment: I see... okay so what if I just make 4 rotated overlapping square divs inside an overlay:hidden div? Maybe I dont really need those extra squares... (I mean without any triangle or whatever, just a rotated square making the triangle shape)

Comment: I was going to suggest exactly that :) https://jsfiddle.net/srmhha2m/5/