# Make only visible part of link clickable

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make something like this:

[image]

Where both sides of the button are clickable and link to a different website (have a guess which ones, heh).

https://jsfiddle.net/3HG6d/1836/

The issue I'm having (as can be seen in the jsfiddle) is that the top `<a>` tag always overlaps the second one, making only one clickable.

CSS:

```
a {
    float:left;
    margin:0.5%;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
}

/*Up-right pointing*/
.triangle-up-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-up-right:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    margin-top:-500px;

    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-top: 500px solid #4679BD;
}

/*Down-left pointing*/
.triangle-down-left {
    width: 10%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-down-left:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
```

**EDIT: should show the correct jsfiddle now**

Comment: whats with the jsfiddle? it doesn't make anysense in this context

Comment: @PhilippSander good point, I edited it but it seems like it didn't save my changes. It should show the right code now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a rotated square div for each one and match the angle that way. On top of this, you'll need to make sure that they are within a wrapper so that you can hide the overflow so that only the visible portion is clickable.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837391/how-to-make-a-triangular-shaped-link-without-using-image-map) could be of use.

Answer (score 0):

use the map and area tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

use poly and form a rectangle

Comment: This isn't very responsive is it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```css
.social-button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.social-button a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.twitter {
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid #4679BD;
}
.facebook {
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 80px solid #BD79BD;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-button">
    <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the facebook button still overlaps the twitter button.